# understanding define functions in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm reading cocos2d-x codes, I found that:

```
int CC_DLL gettimeofday(struct timeval *, struct timezone *);
```

And I found definition of CC_DLL:

```
#define CC_DLL
```

Nothing is here! So what is the point of this CC_DLL?

Comment: Can you post the link of the code that you are reading ?

Comment: One possibility: Depending on how you compile, there could be multiple variants for CC_DLL. The one you found has nothing, another one will actually insert something before gettimeofday

Comment: I found the link, but it is different with mine:https://github.com/richy486/OnMinimalism/blob/master/cocos2dx/platform/win32/CCPlatformDefine.h

Answer (score 1):

These sort of constructs do occur in code that is built for use in shared libraries (aka DLLs) for different platforms.

The purpose is to allow the addition of compiler/environment specific attributes and similar. For example in MS compilers, you'd want `__declspec(dllimport)` where the function is referenced, and `__declspec(dllexport)` where the function is defined. In gcc, you'd use `__attribute__((dllexport))` instead. But if you are not building for Windows in the first place, you may need for example the gcc visibility attribute, `__attribute__((visibility("default"))` may be what you want for these functions.

In this case, it would appear that your compiler and environment "doesn't need such things".

This shows some of these things for gcc:
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility